# Remove quotes from CSV output

Tags: csv, export-to-csv, trifacta

I'm using Trifacta Wrangler to rearrange some datasets, stored in CSV files. I have to produce a CSV file as output, but when I do that Trifacta Wrangler surrounds every value, even integers and floats, with quotes, even if the column type is correctly set. How can I avoid that?

Answer (score 0):

This can be changed by looking under the "More Options" accordion on job run output: there's an option labeled "include quotes" that controls this.